# Array of pointers in shared memory

Tags: c, posix

I'm new to **shared memory** and **posix** so I'm finding trouble doing some basic work.

I have some *Nodes* as following:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int node_id;
    int process_id;
    struct Node* next;
}Entry;
```

I created an array of pointers and in every position there can be a linked list. It functions as a hash table and there are two processes that are editing it.

So there is a chance that there are elements in every position of the array but also there can be a lot of them empty.

I have put in shared memory the array of pointers and not the nodes of the list. So that is a big problem since the node of process 1 are **not visible** by process 2 and otherwise as you can see below.

```
int shmid = shmget(ftok("./main.c", 30), (size_t)(node_num*sizeof(Entry *)), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
if(shmid == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "shmget error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
void* shared_memory = (void*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
if(shared_memory == (void*)-1){
    frpintf(stderr, "shmat error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
Entry** HashTable = (Entry **)shared_memory;
```

To this table both processes will insert and delete nodes. 
I have seen a solution to this problem but it required fixed size of the list, where is a pool of nodes all inside the shared segment, but in my case it isn't fixed since the number is given as a parameter during the execution.

My array functions as a hash table, and the items that can be put are limited so the thing that is worrying me is

1. that from the beginning I will have to put in the segment **X** Nodes and connect them through the hash functions.
2. if I create them with `shmget` and `nodes_num*sizeof(Entry)` as argument, how am I supposed to allocate them ? Because I believe the array of pointers play a vital role in the implementation since a lot of the pointers are `NULL`

So what is the best way to implement this hash table in the shared memory segment?

**EDIT #1**

Comments gave me an idea but I still don't know whether it is a good implementation.

My idea is to keep the array of pointers that I already have, and **ADD** another one array in the shared memory with `size = nodes_num;` and make the first array pointing at certain position of the second one that contains all the data(nodes)

```
int shmid2 = shmget(ftok("./main.c", 30), (size_t)(node_num*sizeof(Entry )), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
if(shmid2 == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "shmget error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
void* shared_memory2 = (void*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
if(shared_memory2 == (void*)-1){
    frpintf(stderr, "shmat error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
Entry* Data = (Entry *)shared_memory2;
```

Comment: you need to put actual nodes into shared memory, then pointer inside every node will point to shared memory too

Comment: I would love to do that, but the truth is I can't find the how. I stumble on a lot of problems.

Comment: I don't see why you want an array of _pointers_. An array of `Entry` should suffice.

Comment: @user58697 I don't think that it would suffice. An array of Entry means I have in every position of the array an entry item. My array is a hash table with a list, so there are positions with no elements at all, and others with more than 1.

Comment: `void* shared_memory2 = (void*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);` the returned pointer can be different for different processes attaching this memory segment. In that case, the `->next` pointers could point outside the address range that the creating process has. **Storing pointers in shm (or (mmapped) files) makes no sense.** Instead of pointers, you should store indexes, or offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly shared memory used for IPC.It means you can put some data in memory and another process will get that data.

so, You can attach array of pointer in shared memory and you will get that all pointers in another process but both process have different stakes so process one have different data in that location and process 2 have different data in its own stack.

For example you are sharing one pointer location **1000** in process1 on 1000 location **"hello"** data inserted then you will share 1000 location to another process while another process go to 1000 location and it will read that location data then you will get segmentation fault because there is nothing on that location which you are going to search.

hope you understood this thing. if your case is different then put this as a NULL (void). thank you.

i have also created data structure in shared memory if you are searching that then tell me i will show you way.

you can pass pointer like this

```
char **array;
char *shared_memory;
int i=0;
array = (char **)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
shared_memory = (char *)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
array[i] = shared_memory;
```

Like wise you can enter all pointers into array of pointers.if you will print all pointer location you will get same.

and you can access like this,

```
int j=0;
fprintf(stdout,"%d",get_data[j++]->node_id);
```

This is full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int node_id;
    int process_id;
    struct Node* next;
}entry;

entry **array;
int shmid;
static int i=0;

void add_begin(entry **hptr_get){

fprintf(stdout,"in add_begin\n");

entry* shared_memory = (entry *)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
if(shared_memory == (void*)-1){
    fprintf(stdout,"shmat error");
    exit(0);
}
array[i++] = shared_memory;

shared_memory->node_id = 1;
shared_memory->process_id = 1;

shared_memory->next = *hptr_get;
*hptr_get = shared_memory;
}

void print(entry **print_data){
int j=1;
while(print_data[j]){

    fprintf(stdout,"%d",print_data[j]->node_id);
    fprintf(stdout,"%d",print_data[j]->process_id);
    print_data[j++];
 }
}

int main(){

int node_num = 10;
key_t key;
key = 4567;
char ans;

   shmid = shmget(key, (size_t)(node_num*sizeof(entry)),0666|IPC_CREAT);
  if(shmid == -1){
    fprintf(stderr,"shmget error");
    exit(0);
 }

array = (entry **)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);

entry *hptr = (entry *)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);

 array[i++]=hptr;

hptr = 0;

do{
    add_begin(&hptr);
    fprintf(stdout,"Do you want to add another data in shared memory?(Y/N)\n");
    fscanf(stdin," %c",&ans);
   }while((ans=='y')||(ans=='Y'));
 array[++i] = 0;
 print(array);
 }
```

Comment: I know that this is happening. I want to keep the array of pointers and also have all of my data in the shared segment. The thing is I don't know how

Comment: Please refer my edited answer it might help you. but i request you don't go in this way if your another Process want data then put data itself in shared memory not pointer and fire signal to another process, so your another process will handle that signal and will go in shared memory and get that particular data and do farther work. I was in same situation like you are in right now but i prefer this way to overcome this problem.